# Problem with centering minipage

Tags: minipage

The problem I am facing is about centering the middle minipage in the top of the first page. I tried to use `\begin{center}` inside the minipage environment to have the text in center of the minipage but the problem is that text doesn't show up in the **TOP center** of the hall page like the text shown in the following picture.

[image]

Although I am getting this :

[image]

I have defined in the code that institutional Name should be aligned in the middle, but as you can see, the text is heading little bit to the right side of the page.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}


\begin{flushleft}

\includegraphics[width=3cm ,height=3cm]{../Capture.PNG}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}


\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{Large}
\emph{Ecole National Supérieur des travaux Publics}
\end{Large}
```

If someone knows how to solve the problem, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with this code fragment, which we can compile as it is.

Answer (score 1):

From your incomplete code fragment is impossible reproduce what you show in your second image. As one of possible solution of your problem can be use of `tabularx` table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % it loaded package graphicx

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{CCC}
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm,valign=t]{example-image-duck}  %{../Capture.PNG}
    &   \Large\itshape
        Ecole National Supérieur des travaux Publics
        &   some text not included in the code example
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text area borders)

Answer (score 0):

A solution with the `adjustwidth` environment from `changepage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{changepage} 

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustwidth}{-3cm}{-3cm}
\leavevmode
\rlap{\includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=t]{enstp}}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth}
\centering
\makebox[0pt]{\Large
\emph{École Nationale Supérieure des Travaux Publics}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\llap{\includegraphics[scale=0.25,valign =t]{nr_y}}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]